# Read items into a file whose name contains some space from a batch script

Tags: file, batch-file

I need to read items inside some files from a batch script. The name of certain items' file contains some spaces. To do that, I use the file name as a parameter, which is surrounded by double quotes in order to take account file names with spaces.

```
read.bat
 for /F %%a in ("%~1") do echo %%a>>result.txt

conf file.TXT
 projectId: BIEW
 artifactId: SPRINT1
```

Batch is running like this  'read.bat conf file.TXT'. Instead having into result.txt

```
 projectId: BIEW
 artifactId: SPRINT1
```

I get "conf", first part of the file name. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `"delims="`, session protocol:

```
>type read.bat
@for /F "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("%~1") do @echo %%a

>type "conf file.txt"
1
2
3
4
5

>read.bat "conf file.TXT"
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Thanks. It's works fine by the use of usebackqdelims. please what the main difference between usebackqdelims and delims? I have read stuff sometimes about usebackqdelims but I ever didn't understand its goal. Thanks again

Comment: if you need to reed text files with spaces in the file name, the name must be surrounded by double quotes. now `usebackq` must be added, Otherwise windows reads not the file but the _file name_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ("%~1") do echo %%a>>result.txt
```

Dave Ruhmann is correct.  Depending on how you are using result.txt, you may want to do this instead:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ("%~1") do echo "%%a">>result.txt
```

Comment: I get the same result as previously: "conf".    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the file name is not within quotations when it is passed to the script.
`read.bat conf file.TXT`

It needs to be

`read.bat "conf file.TXT"`

If not, then you will have to use both the first and second parameters `%1 %2` because the space is interpreted as a break in parameter.

Comment: After trying, I get "conf file.TXT" and not each item of data file in result.txt. Thanks